# Automating options when using apt-get install

Tags: linux, docker, apt

I have this step in my dockerfile

```
RUN apt install libpq-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev -y
```

And when I build it, it stuck with the prompts

[image]

How do I get pass this with pre-selected options?

Comment: OK Found this https://askubuntu.com/questions/909277/avoiding-user-interaction-with-tzdata-when-installing-certbot-in-a-docker-contai

Comment: Instead of `apt`, use `apt-get` in scripts & automation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install tzdata on a ubuntu docker image?](https://serverfault.com/questions/949991/how-to-install-tzdata-on-a-ubuntu-docker-image)

Comment: Thanks I have solved my problem yesterday.